# Potential difference across a wire

Tags: electricity, electric-current

Why potential difference across no resistance wire is same across two points.

Comment: Suppose it weren't the same. How much current would flow in the wire?

Comment: The current would depend upon the battery and that's what I am asking if v=constant why current flows.

Comment: OK, suppose you connected a "zero resistance" wire across a battery with nonzero internal resistance. What ends up being the voltage across the wire? Suppose the battery has 1 ohm resistance and the wire has 0.01 ohms. Or 0.001 ohms. What's the limit as the wire resistance goes to zero?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Potential difference across a zero resistance wire](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409310/)

Comment: Also: [How electric currents can flow between 2 points at the same potential?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45040/22927)

Comment: My question is that why potential difference across a wire (free wires in circuits) is zero. This means that potential is same across two ends of a wire means no work is being done to carry that charge but that cannot be the case.

Answer (score -2):

Potential difference between point A and point B : Work done by the *electric field* in moving the charge from A to B.

If two points are separated by a resistance-less conductor, Then the electric field inside the conductor is zero.Thus,The charges experience *zero* electric force, and thus No work is done in moving the charges, and hence there is no potential *difference*.

Comment: Then by your answer we should get shock even if conducting wire is not connected to a battery. As current is flowing without any potential difference.