# EMF Generated according to Faraday's Law

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, potential, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

According to Faraday's Law, due to a relative movement between the current carrying loop and the magnetic field, an EMF is induced in the loop causing a current flow. However, according to Maxwell-Faraday's Law,
$$\nabla \times \bf E = -\frac{\partial \bf B}{\partial t}$$
Clearly, if the magnetic field changes, the electric field becomes non-conservative and electric potential is no longer defined. In that case, how can we even define the emf of the circuit? What does induced emf actually mean then?

Comment: *How can we even define the emf?* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromotive_force#Formal_definitions

Comment: Do answers to this question  help? ( https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/692912/what-is-the-difference-between-emf-induced-in-faradays-law-and-the-potential-di? )

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I went through that already but I feel like those answers are kind of unrelated to what I'm exactly looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can we even define the emf of the circuit?

The EMF is defined as a line integral of the electric field.

> According to Faraday's Law, due to a relative movement between the current carrying loop and the magnetic field, an EMF is induced in the loop

Notice the wording: The EMF is induced *on (or around) the loop*, not "between two points" as we would say about a potential difference.

Of course we can also have an EMF for an open path between two points (as opposed to a loop), but we must specify the path to be taken between the points. The EMF between the points can be different for different paths between the points.

> Clearly, if the magnetic field changes, the electric field becomes non-conservative

Again, this is exactly it. If the field were conservative, then the EMF around any loop in that field would be 0. Only with a non-conservative field can we have a non-zero EMF around a closed loop.

Since we define the EMF for each path of integration between two points, the EMF will be well-defined even when the potential difference between two points in a system is not.

Comment: So induced EMF is different from the 'regular' emf, like the one which has to do with batteries?